# PHP forced download jpg -- viewer saying file is corrupt

Tags: php, http-headers

I am just having one heck of a time with this, I am using php to force download files from my database to the ole'desktop, the download part is fine, then when I go to open the file (in viewer if it is jpg) the application tells me the file is corrupted

Here is is the html

```
<form action="view_file.php" method="post" name="downloadform">
      <input name="file_name" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $row['file_path'];?>>
      <input name="file_type" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $row['file_type'];?>>
      <button type="submit" value="Secure Download" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 btn btn-default pull-left view_file"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span> Secure Download</button>
</form>
```

This is my php snippet 
    //clean output buffer
    ob_clean();

```
//If statement gets everything started
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){

     //Grab global variables from the HTML form
     $file = $_POST['file_name'];
     $file_type2 = $_POST['file_type'];

     //Grab last item in array then explode to only grab the file name
     $filename = array_pop(explode('/', $file));

          //Grab file type from global variables in HTML form
          header("Content-type: ".$file_type2."");

          ////Grab file path from global variables in HTML form
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
          readfile($file);
               exit();
}
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: open file with text editor, check the top for php errors or html

Comment: The error I found was <b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>

Comment: You should check what file is being requested, otherwise one could download any file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you are trying to readfile on an incomplete filename. Try

```
$fullfilename = $filename.'.'.$file_type2;
readfile($fullfilename);
```

And see what happens. Also, like others have said... open the file with a text editor and read the error. You may need to turn error reporting on. You do that with

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message "Only variables should be passed by reference" says, you are giving a constant value to a function that use a param passed by reference.

I think the problem is here :

```
$filename = array_pop(explode('/', $file));
```

array_pop first param is passed by reference, as the array is modified during the process. You should use a temporary variable :

```
$filepathArray = explode('/', $file);
$filename = array_pop($filepathArray);
```

Or even better, use the basename function that is best suited for what you want to do :

```
$filename = basename($file);
```

Comment: Hey Lucas, the problem im running into to is that even when I use basename its telling me that the $filename variable is emtpy, in my database I have the full path saved, basename() gives me the end of that path, but I think then it cant access the file since the path is gone, do you know anyway around this?

Comment: Warning: readfile(test.odt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\casekeeper_directory\view_file.php on line 9

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a similar problem.

This is because readfile() has a kind of buffer of 4096 bytes.

this means that when your page is reloaded by clicking submit

whatever is written BEFORE your readfile() goes into this buffer, before to start the download.

BUT this "whatever" is greateer than 4096 bytes, the exceeding part gets jammed with the file to be dowloaded, corrupting it.

try bring the snpiset at the beginning of your view_file.php, instead than at the end.